# Sarah writes the letter

Tags: grammar

> Simple Present
>
> Sarah **writes** the letter.
>
> Present Continuous
>
> *Right now, Sarah **is writing** the letter.*
>
> Simple Past
>
> *Sarah **writed** the letter.*

Why Simple Present and Simple Past do not need to put "is"?

Comment: Wrote, not writed. I'm not sure there *is* a why… you just don't. "Sarah is writes.. is just wrong.

Comment: The short answer is "because that's how tenses work in English". BTW, the past tense of *write* is irregular: *Sarah **wrote** the letter* (not *writed*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the simple forms show tense.  The participle forms do not show tense.

> Sara *wrote*. -- *wrote* indicates the past, nothing indicates continuous
>   Sara *writes*.  -- *writes* indicates the present, nothing indicates continuous
>
> Sara *was* writing. -- *was* indicates the past, *writing* indicates continuous
>   Sara *is* writing. -- *is* indicates the present, *writing* indicates continuous